# when drop partition and update global indexes exists error :a partition maintenance operation may not be combined with other operations

Tags: oracle, partitioning

Here I wrote a Oracle SP to drop the partition and  update the global index.
but It encountered an error ,

```
begin
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session set nls_date_format="YYYY-MM-DD"';
dbms_output.put_line(need_housekeeping_month);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE pos_data DROP PARTITION FOR (need_housekeeping_month))  UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES';

end;
```

I searched some solutions but no idea on that,Please help.

```
 ORA-14048: a partition maintenance operation may not be combined with other operations

        Cause: The ALTER TABLE or ALTER INDEX statement attempted to combine a partition maintenance operation (for example, MOVE PARTITION) with some other operation (for example, ADD PARTITION or PCTFREE) which is illegal.

        Action: Ensure that a partition maintenance operation is the sole operation specified in an ALTER TABLE or ALTER INDEX statement; operations other than those dealing with partitions, default attributes of partitioned tables/indices, or specifying that a table be renamed (ALTER TABLE RENAME) can be combined.
```

for add another question

```
    create or replace procedure   SP_HOUSE_KEEPING(p_dt_cycle_dt in VARCHAR2) is
hotspot_data_months number :=27;
need_housekeeping_month DATE := ADD_MONTHS( to_date(p_dt_cycle_dt,'yyyymmdd'), -(hotspot_data_months-1) );
begin
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session set nls_date_format="YYYY-MM-DD"';
dbms_output.put_line(need_housekeeping_month);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE pos_data DROP PARTITION FOR (need_housekeeping_month)  UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES';
end;
```

ORA-14755: Invalid partition specification for FOR VALUES clause.

Comment: Your `()`are unbalanced

Comment: Thannks @Mat,revised but found another error ,ORA-14755: Invalid partition specification for FOR VALUES clause.  This SQL is worked,but why use variable,it can't? ALTER TABLE pos_data DROP PARTITION FOR (TO_DATE('2017-03-31','YYYY-MM-DD'))  UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;

Comment: Why do you specify `p_dt_cycle_dt` as `VARCHAR2` rather than `DATE` or at least `INTEGER`?

Comment: As it is the first time to write the SP, Not quite clear which type should be used....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put the partition as variable, try this one:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE pos_data DROP PARTITION FOR (DATE '''||to_char(need_housekeeping_month, 'YYYY-MM-DD')||''') UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES';
```

Comment: Thanks,@Wernfried,Awesome.